# How to send namedtuples between tranformations?

Tags: bonobo-etl

How to send out a row as namedtuple from one Bonobo transformation? So in the receiving transformation I have field-level access to row data.

I'm now using dicts to send data between transformations. But they have a disadvantage: they're mutable (bad things can happen if you forgot to create a fresh one at output of transformation).

I thought that simply replacing a dict with a namedtuple would do the trick, but apparently Bonobo doesn't support sending out a namedtuple. I read something about context.set_output_fields[list of keys]), but can't figure out how to use it. A small example would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Using namedtuple is very straightforward, you can yield a namedtuple instance and retrieve it expanded as the next transformation input:

```py
import bonobo
import collections

Hero = collections.namedtuple("Hero", ["name", "power"])


def produce():
    yield Hero(name="Road Runner", power="speed")
    yield Hero(name="Wile E. Coyote", power="traps")
    yield Hero(name="Guido", power="dutch")


def consume(name, power):
    print(name, "has", power, "power")


def get_graph():
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph >> produce >> consume
    return graph


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with bonobo.parse_args() as options:
        bonobo.run(get_graph())
```

The "output fields" of `produce()` will be set from the namedtuple fields, and the "input fields" of `consume(...)` will be detected from the first input row.

The `context.set_output_fields(...)` method is only useful if for whatever reason you don't want to used named datastructures (like namedtuples) but prefer to use tuples, yet needing to name the values in the tuple.

Hope that helps!